# Transition effect - Trying to create the simplest slideout nav

Tags: javascript, html, css

Thanks in advance for your support... I am trying to make a simple slide out navigation

So without any experience in javascript and after 2 days trying to find a SIMPLE solution for a slideout nav I was only able to come across some scripts that were to big… some were 20kb or more or two complicated to implement.

I believe that simplicity is the ultimate sophistication and I knew there should be a better way so after many hours trying... I was able to come up with this solution witch I got from different sources.

```
<script>
var slider = document.querySelector('.slider');
var overlay = document.querySelector('.overlay');

function openSlide() {
if (slider.classList.contains('closed')) {
  slider.classList.remove('closed');
  slider.classList.add('open');
  overlay.classList.remove('no-display');
} else {
  slider.classList.remove('open');
  slider.classList.add('closed');
  overlay.classList.add('no-display');
}
}

function closeSlide() {
slider.classList.remove('open');
slider.classList.add('closed');
overlay.classList.add('no-display');
}

</script>
```

My questions are...

How can I improve my code? (without making it to complicated to understand- at least for me)

Is there a way to use a transition effect in the Visibility Property in  .overlay from "none" to "block" ?

You can see see an example here...

https://jsfiddle.net/8na6t0dg/2/

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, the best approach for the slideout nav menu is to place it off the screen. Like this:
[image]

These are the things that you need to keep in mind:

1. Place the sidemenu off the screen
2. Use absolute position (or fixed, depending on your requirements)
3. `transition` the `left` css property.
4. Use javascript only for toggle the class or css rule that change the `left` property.

Here's a very simple demo:
http://codepen.io/sospedra/pen/ezNWgW

Comment: I already got it to work... if you check my fiddle you will see that I have already achieved the slideout effect... its the overlay that i need to put an effect on... while I was searching for the best solution for my problem I read that we should not use the transition on the left top etc property for performance reasons. you should check my fiddle...

Comment: The thing about the perfomance is simply not true. But, even if it was, that's micro optimization, which is a bad pattern. Check my codepen again, now contains the overlay.

Comment: After many attempts I got to this solution https://jsfiddle.net/8na6t0dg/6/ it is important for the user to be able to close the slider by clicking on the overlay. I was able to fix my problem before I saw your post. I don't understand you script ( my fault) so I will use mine instead... Anyway I will set your answer as the correct one. Gracias

Comment: If you need it I can guide you through the code ;) Just let me know

Comment: For some weird reason I don't understand my script is performing sluggish in Firefox.. does anyone knows what is wrong.. I am using el capitan and the the script doesn't perform the same in safari and firefox... didn't tried chrome Fiddle jsfiddle.net/8na6t0dg/6

Answer (score 0):

If you had only toggle slide button then you could just use this code:

```
var slider = document.querySelector('.slider');
var overlay = document.querySelector('.overlay');
var opened = false;

function toggleSlide() {
if (!opened) {
    slider.classList.remove('closed');
    slider.classList.add('open');
    overlay.classList.remove('no-display');
  } else {
    slider.classList.remove('open');
    slider.classList.add('closed');
    overlay.classList.add('no-display');
  }
  opened = !opened;
}
```

And there is no way to use transition on this property. Changing the opacity immediately after a timeout is a good solution:

```
overlay.classList.add('no-display');
setTimeout(function(){
   overlay.style.opacity = '1';
},0);
```

Comment: After your seeing your comment I have made some changes to my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/8na6t0dg/3/ and now just new to put the timeout function correctly after the opacity transition is completed. it should follow this order:  display none... display block and only then must come the transition effect, on close the reverse will happen.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to make this as simple as I could for you.  This strategy uses css transforms to show and hide the slideout.

```js
// --------------------------
// Initialize the slideout and return a function that when called
// toggles the slideout
// --------------------------
var toggleSlideShow = (function(slideOutId) {
  var mySlideOut = document.getElementById(slideOutId);

  // --------------------------
  // utility to toggle the required classes to animate the slideout
  // --------------------------
  var _toggle = function() {
    mySlideOut.querySelector(".mainOverlay").classList.toggle("slideOutShow");
    mySlideOut.querySelector(".slideOutContainer").classList.toggle("slideOutShow");
  };
  // --------------------------

  // --------------------------
  // add handler to close slideout on overlay click
  // --------------------------
  mySlideOut.querySelector(".mainOverlay").addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (this.classList.contains("slideOutShow")) { _toggle(); }
  });
  // --------------------------

  return _toggle;

})("slideOut1");
// --------------------------


// --------------------------
// add handler to toggle slideout on button click
// --------------------------
document.getElementById("slideToggler").addEventListener("click", function() {
  toggleSlideShow();
});
// --------------------------
```

```css
.mainContainer {
  margin: 1em;
  background-image: url("https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/05/84/44/058444b369252478964babaf2361fb15.jpg");
  background-size: cover;

  /* important styles */
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.mainOverlay {
  min-height: 500px;
  background-color: #000;

  /* important styles */
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s ease;
}

.slideOutContainer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1em;
  width: 200px;
  min-height: 50px;
  background-color: aliceblue;
  transition: transform .5s ease;
  transform: translateX(-200px);
}

.slideOutContainer.slideOutShow { transform: translateX(0px); }
.mainOverlay.slideOutShow { opacity: 0.5; }
```

```html
<button id="slideToggler">toggle</button>

<div id="slideOut1" class="mainContainer">
  <div class="mainOverlay"></div>
  <div class="slideOutContainer">
    <div style="text-align: center;">contents of slide</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi. thanks for your reply. Probably I didn't explain myself very well but I have already achieved the slide out effect. But its the overlay that is not having any transition aplied to it... you should check my fiddle

Comment: sorry about that.  You want a "transition" on the the overlay as well.  I'll see what I can do

Comment: check my last fiddle.... [link]https://jsfiddle.net/8na6t0dg/3/ the transition is already there... just need to make it "disappear" after the opacity transition is completed.

Comment: Ok, I added some opacity to the slide effect.  I think it is still fairly simple